# Matlab run commands asynchronously

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to put the calling of function into another thread? I tried `spmd` in the function but i get error saying that

> MATLAB cannot determine whether "System" refers to a function or
>   variable.

```
tic
Speak('Testing');
toc
...next line of code...

function Speak(text)
spmd
NET.addAssembly('System.Speech');
speak = System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer;
speak.Volume = 100;
speak.Speak(text);
end
end
```

I get elapsed time of approximately 2 seconds, which is pretty long for this purpose. I would prefer the speech continuing in the background and proceed to the next line of code in the meantime.